# Functions with `$this` don't work in Base class PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have recently started working with OO PHP and I've come across an error.

I have a base class `BaseController.php`

and a class `DatabaseController.php` which extends `BaseController.php`

At the moment these classes are pretty basic but I want a few reusable functions in Base and overall this has been successful.

However, I am trying to use functions in the Base Controller together and it seems functions with `$this->functionName();` don't return anything.

Here is my code to further explain:

**Base Controller**

```
public function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_name");
    return $conn;
}

public function getSource($id) {
    $conn = $this->connectDB();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sources WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $name = $row['slug'];
    }
    return $name;
}

public function mapColumnsToFunctions($row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "source") {
            $result = $this->getSource($value);
            $row["source_slug"] = $result;
        }
        return $row;
    }
}
```

**Database Controller**

```
class DatabaseController extends BaseController {
   public function getDataItem($type, $id) {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        $id = $this->checkField($id, "");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $type WHERE id = '$id'";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $response = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $response[$type][] = $this->mapColumnsToFunctions($row);        
        }
        $response = json_encode($response);
        return $response;   
    }
}
```

I should be seeing a JSON response with `source_slug` as a field but this isn't coming through to the feed.

```
{
  "id": "213023",
  "name": "Source Name",
  "url": "http://sample.url",
  "source": "1"
  // NO source_slug: "english equiv of 1"
},
```

Comment: Is it your real code for `Database Controller`?

Comment: You can't have code outside a function definition in the `DatabaseController` class.

Comment: And if you follow the logic you show in baseController you are going to be making MANY connections where ONE is enough

Comment: In `getSource`, you overwrite `$name` every time through the loop. So you only return the value from the last row of the results.

Comment: @u_mulder I can confirm it is within a function. A bit further along in my PHP than that ;) - I will edit to avoid future sarcy comments.

Comment: Where is the method?

Comment: @WebDevDanno Obviously it's really in a function, but we need to see the function so we can see if it sets `$query`, `$response`, and `$type` correctly.

Comment: @Barmar Or he has an unnecessary loop to retrieve only one row!

Comment: @RiggsFolly But he's "further along in his PHP than that"!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **Nobody here is ClairVoyant** We can only comment on what we **SEE**

Comment: Added fuller code for a clearer question, I hope.

Comment: define `getDataItem` in `getDataItem`??

Comment: oops sorry - will amend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapColumnsToFunctions` has a `return` statement inside the `foreach` loop. So it returns immediately during the first iteration, even if it hasn't updated anything in `$row`.

The `return` statement should be after the loop.

```
public function mapColumnsToFunctions($row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "source") {
            $result = $this->getSource($value);
            $row["source_slug"] = $result;
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```

The loop seems unnecessary (unless it's an abbreviation of what you're really doing). It could be rewritten as:

```
public function mapColumnsToFunctions($row) {
    if (isset($row["source"])) {
        $row["slug_source"] = $this->getSource($row["source"]);
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar - fixed instantly. I was over complicating and thinking OO was the problem. I am NOW further along in PHP ;)

Comment: Great suggestion about checking `isset($row)` - instantly more efficient and makes for more sense, thank you.